# ¿Por qué la instancia de padre no tiene método de la interfaz que implementa la clase hijo?

Tags: java, poo, herencia

Dispongo de una clase `A` ,luego una clase `B` que hereda de `A` y luego una clase `C` que hereda de `B` e implementa una interfaz `C`.

Sería algo así:

```
          public class A {}
          public class B extends A {}
          public class C extends B implements Cinterface{}
```

La interface tiene un método llamémosle

```
              void Coger(){}
```

Si en la clase `Main` creo un objeto de la clase `B` – que hereda de la clase `A`

```
               B Hola = new B("Ra.one",12,93,84);
```

No entiendo por qué el objeto de la clase `B` que acabo de crear no tiene el acceso al método `void Coger()` de la interface `Cinterface` si esta dentro de la clase `C` que hereda de la clase `B`.

¿Qué hago mal?

Comment: "Todos los hombres son animales. Si los hombres pueden pensar ¿significa eso que cualquier animal puede pensar?". Si creas una instancia de B (animal), no puedes afirmar que pueda pensar (método `coger`)

Comment: Para eso A tendría que implementar Cinterface, no C que es un subtipo

Comment: Entiendo por lo que dices que lógicamente la clase B tiene los atributos y métodos de la clase A pero no los de la clase C por lo tanto el Objeto B trendria acceso a todo A pero no para abajo a C,es correcto?...Es que en el Main de la aplicación se me pide que el objeto "Hola" de la clase B pueda acceder al método Void coger de la Clase C que implementa de la interface Cinterface....¿Que hago mal? Un saludo! @SJuan76

Comment: @Awes0meM4n Entonces quedaría de la siguiente manera,,,Public class A implements Cinterface ,   public class B extendes A y por ultimo Public class C extendes B estoy en lo cierto?

Comment: Así sí que podría usar Coger(). pero no tendría acceso mediante la clase C, sino mediante A. Para que fuera mediante C que es lo primero que has dicho sería `public class B extends C`; `public class C implements Cinterface`

Comment: @Awes0meM4n cierto,como dices lo que quería es lo primero y tal como dices funciona correctamente.Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Primero, algo de concepto

En el paradigma de la programación orientada a objetos, específicamente en la herencia y el polimorfismo, el verbo **ser** es de mucha utilidad para aclarar la mente (y algunos conceptos).

Una jerarquía de clases, implica que un objeto de una clase descendiente **es** una instancia válida de la clase padre, pero no al revés.

Es más fácil verlo con un ejemplo, solo que en lugar de dar nombres totalmente abstractos a las clases, les daremos nombres de alguna jerarquía conocida que nos ayude a entender el ejemplo.

Supongamos que tenemos la siguiente jerarquía:

```
                 SerVivo
                    |
       ------------------------------------------
       |            |            |              |
    Planta       Animal       Bacteria       Otros...
       |            |            |
     (sus           |          (sus
 descendientes)     |      descendientes)
                    |
      -----------------------------
      |             |             |
   Vivíparo      Mamífero       Otros...
      |             |             |
    (sus            |           (sus
descendientes)      |        descendientes)
                    | 
       --------------------------
       |            |           |
     Perro       Humano       Gato
```

Si tomamos una instancia (objeto) de la clase Humano, ese Humano **es** a su vez un mamífero, **es** un animal y **es** un ser vivo.

Pero si tomamos una instancia de cualquiera de `SerVivo`, ese ser vivo no necesariamente **es** un Animal, es decir, podría serlo, pero también podría ser una Planta, una Bacteria u otro tipo de ser viviente.

Esta es la razón por la que es válido hacer asignaciones como estas:

```
SerVivo x;
Humano y = new Humano();
x = y;  //a x se le puede asignar y, ya que y **es** un SerVivo.

//de hecho, pudimos haber hecho directamente algo como:

SerVivo x = new Humano();
SerVivo y = new ArbolDeLimon();
SerVivo z;
z = x;
z = y;
```

### Ahora, a tu pregunta

Esa es la razón por la que una instancia de la clase `B` no tiene los métodos declarados en la clase descendiente `C`.

Volvamos al ejemplo.

Podemos imaginar algunos métodos básicos de `SerVivo`, tales como

```
void nacer();
void crecer();
void reproducirse();
void morir();
```

Al declararlos en la clase `SerVivo`, todos los seres vivos (instancias de clases que heredan de nuestra clase abstracta `SerVivo`) tendrán esos 4 métodos disponibles.

Si vamos hacia abajo, podemos imaginar algunos métodos de clases tales como

```
Animal: 
char sexo;
void mirar();

Mamífero:
void amamantarCrio(Mamifero crio);
void moverCola();

Perro:
void ladrar();

Humano:
void pensar();
void hablar(String texto);
```

El hecho de que algunos de estos métodos sean parte de la implementación de una interfaz es irrelevante. Lo importante es que puedes ver que tiene sentido que el método `hablar();` no existe en una instancia de `Mamífero`, ni en una instancia de `SerVivo`. Este método solamente existe en las instancias de SerHumano.

Más allá de eso, aún cuando tengas una instancia de Humano, pero la referencias con una variable de una clase ancestro, tampoco puedes acceder a los métodos de la clase descendiente, solamente a los declarados en la clase sobre la que has declarado la variable. Puedes resolver esto aplicando moldes de tipo.

Volviendo a los ejemplos:

```
SerVivo x;
Humano y = new Humano();
x = y;  //a x se le puede asignar y, ya que y **es** un SerVivo.
y.hablar("Hola");    // esto es válido.
x.hablar("que tal");  <--- error de compilación
```

Answer (score 1):

Si querés que tu objeto tenga acceso al método Coger.
Deberías de instanciar tu objeto a C

```
C Hola = new C("Ra.one",12,93,84);
```

Tu clase B no tiene el método Coger. Entonces no te va a funcionar.
Tu clase C tiene el método Coger, te va a funcionar.

```
Hola.Coger();
```

Answer (score 1):

Principalmente no tiene el método Coger por que C es quien implementa Cinterface, si te fijas en tu código

```
      public class A {} 
      public class B extends A {} -> B Solo extiende de A
      public class C extends B implements Cinterface{} -> Al extender de B no le va a pasar sus métodos a B, sino que toma los métodos de B.
```

Por lo que podrías hacer para que tengan ambos la misma interfaz es lo siguiente:

```
      public class A {}
      public class B extends A implements Cinterface{}
      public class C extends B {}
```

Con eso haces la implementación de Coger en B y si necesitas sobreescribir el método en C lo podrás realizar sin problemas pudiendo utilizarlo así:

```
B objetoC = new C();
objetoC.Coger(); //Ejecutará el código de B si no tiene sobreescrito el método, si lo tiene ejecutará el de la clase C.
```